# link outside google maps to center map on marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a google map with multiple markers. Outside the map, there's the list of markers that are displayed on the map. I want to be able to make links out of thise listed addresses, and when I click them, center the map on the corresponding marker (without erasing all the other markers).

Comment: Do you have any code sample? Where are you storing your coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a link as you add the marker to center on it in Google Maps v3:

```
function addMarker(myMap, myAddress, myLat, myLng) {
    // Create Google Maps LatLng from position
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng);

    // Create the marker
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: myMap
       position: myLatLng
    });

    // Create a new anchor, bind click, and append to the container
    $("<a></a>")
        .attr("href", "#")
        .html(myAddress)
        .click(function() {
            myMap.setCenter(myLatLng);
        })
        .appendTo(".myLinkContainer");
}
```

It's probably best you do it as you create the marker so you don't have to maintain a reference to the `LatLng` object defining the position in a window-level object.